# get product name with category name and subcategories name in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, tree

I need category name with product name, I have two tables in databse categories and prodcuts, i want to get products regarding or with referance of related category
Example:-

Category and subcatagory with list

Comment: What did you try so far ? have you relations in the model ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a many-to-many relationship, because each product can have multiple categories and each category can be associated to multiple products.

Laravel documentation is pretty good, you can check it out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Assuming your models are `Product` and `Category`, you can do as follows:

Inside your `Product.php` class:

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

Inside your `Category.php` class:

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

Now you need to create the table in the DB to support the relationship (in a many-yo-many relationship, this table is called `pivot`)

Create a new migration similar to the following:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('category_product');
}
```

Now you can get the categories of a product very simply:

```
$product->categories; // You get a collection of categories
$product->categories(); // You get the query if you need to add some filters
```

In a similar way, you get all the products of a specific category with:

```
$category->products;
```

To add a category to your product, you can do in many ways, some are:

```
$product->categories()->attach($category_id);
$product->categories()->sync([$category_id1, $category_id2, ..]);
```

For more details of specific needs, you can read through the documentation i linked above